# When a witch or wizard influences your life in a negative manner

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, verbs

Imagine someone (a bad-doer or someone who can't bear to see your success or for some reasons is jealous of you) deals with malicious, magical sort of things (perhaps a witch) influences your life and somewhat changes your life in a bad way. Which one of the following verbs work in my example properly:

> I'm sure! She has.........(me. / my life.)
>
> - **a)** [spelled](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spell)
> - **b)** [enchanted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enchant)

Based on dictionary definitions, they both sound to be correct, but I'm not sure if a native speaker would say it in the same way and the used verbs in this sense sounds old-fashioned or something.

If they are not natural in this sense, what verb is used in this sense?

[It can be considered as superstition, but in eastern culture at least you hear a lot about these things.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of your suggestions seem to fit - *spelled* can't be used as a verb in this fashion, and *enchanted* has a very positive overtone. I could be enchanted by a beautiful lady, for example.

I believe that ***cursed*** might be the word you are looking for.

A [curse](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curse) can mean a spell that calls upon divine or supernatural power to bring harm or ill fortune to someone, therefore to be cursed means to be affected by a curse that causes bad things to happen.

To use your examples:

> She has cursed me.
>
> She has cursed my life.

Answer (score 4):

A witch is rarely to *enchant* you unless she is remarkably beautiful. Witches are more likely to [jinx](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jinx) you or [hex](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hex) you. 
Both words have *evil connotations* :***to affect as if by an evil spell***.

> She *jinxed* me.
>   She has *put a hex* on me.
>   She has *hexed* my life.

Comment: While hexed and jinxed both could be used, as a native English speaker I find cursed to be the more natural.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Yes me too.'Hex' is not as common but I've heard 'jinx' informally being used.

Comment: I think jinxed or hexed is appropriate but it is usually "She jinxed me." (not "my life") Jinxed is to me a more mild statement of inviting bad luck - for example, "I think this will be easy, but I hope I didn't just jinx us by saying that."

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for correcting me. A more sinister term for me is [hoodooed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hoodooed), but is rarely used.

Comment: **hex** as a verb is AmE, but its usage in the UK is increasing. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hex

Comment: "Jinx" doesn't need a human agent --  "I walked under a ladder, and this jinxed me for the rest of the day" -- 'jinx' meaning 'to bring bad luck'. "Hex", on the other hand, requires a human agent, someone to invoke the hex  or curse. But you definitely hear "cursed" more often than either of these.

Answer (score 1):

A purely Australian take on this... indigenous Australians have a ceremony in which they place a curse on someone by a kurdaitcha man "pointing the bone" at them. If you have had the bone pointed at you, you will die within a short time!

Interestingly, in 2004, indigenous Australians who disagreed with his policies carried out this ritual on the Australian Prime Minister, John Howard. He is still alive and healthy 12 years later!

On the other hand, there are instances of Australian natives appearing in hospital claiming that the bone has been pointed at them, and dying within a few days. On autopsy, no cause of death could be found.

Comment: It turns out that [placebos can be more effective than drugs](http://science.howstuffworks.com/life/inside-the-mind/human-brain/placebo-effect.htm) for some people, so sometimes just believing something is going to have a certain effect can be enough .